# PDF files are printed as blank pages.

Tags: printing, pdf

I'm trying to print a PDF file with Document Viewer.

I get blank pages out of printer.

When I hit Print preview, I also see blank pages.

Images (jpg) are printed just fine.

The problem appeared recently, I can't figure out what caused the problem.

How I can make my printer print PDF?

Answer (score 1):

aha i solved my issue ,i was printing direct from a website pdf . viewing the pdf in mozilla and trying to print direct from there,

it just printed blanks for some reason, print head didnt even move just sucked paper in and spat it back out every time. i then downloaded the pdf and opened it in document viewer and it printed fine, have you tried downloading adobe reader for ubuntu http://get.adobe.com/reader/otherversions/ if it is a similar issue to me it might not be your printer but the program you are viewing the pdf in, sorry i'm not more helpful